# HTTP Debug Recorder and Auto-responder

Tags: debugging, http, fiddler

Can you recommend a good HTTP Debug Recorder and Autoresponder?
I usually use [*fiddler*'s](http://www.fiddler2.com) autoresponder, but it does not enable rules to be set by POST information, only by querystring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiddler can absolutely return automatically generated responses based on the content of a POST body, you simply cannot do it with the UI. Click Rules > Customize Rules, and enter your script inside the OnBeforeRequest handler.

```
if (oSession.uriContains("postpage.aspx") && 
  oSession.utilFindInRequest("mypostname=value"))
{
  oSession["x-replywithfile"] = "C:\\fakeresponse.htm"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For complex stuff, I'd recommend http::recorder and www::mechanize (PERL modules) see [this article](http://www.perl.com/lpt/a/845) for an example.

But for simpler stuff, I use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and/or a quick PHP script

HTH

C.